# How to fit a certain bounds consisting of NE and SW coordinates into the visible map view?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I need to fit a certain bounds within a map. I get the bounds from calling the google geocoder and reading the viewport property which looks like:

```
{
    northeast =     {
        lat = "30.4212235";
        lng = "-97.486942";
    };
    southwest =     {
        lat = "30.1128403";
        lng = "-97.99917959999999";
    };
}
```

I then convert these into CLLocationCoordinate2D

```
NSDictionary *viewport = [[[results objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"] 
                                                     objectForKey:@"viewport"];
NSDictionary *NEDictionary = [viewport objectForKey:@"northeast"];
NSDictionary *SWDictionary = [viewport objectForKey:@"southwest"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D SWCoordinate = 
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        [[SWDictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue], 
        [[SWDictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue]
    );
CLLocationCoordinate2D NECoordinate = 
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        [[NEDictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue], 
        [[NEDictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue]
    );
```

I know I need to generate a MKMapRect (or MKMapRegion, whichever is easier) from these coordinates and then [mapView setVisibleRect:newRect animated:YES] (or [mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES] but I'm not quite sure how to get there. I need a method to convert the bounds into the proper data structure, something like:

```
- (MKMapRect) mapRectThatFitsBoundsSW:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)sw 
                                   NE:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)ne {
    // CGFloat x = ??
    // CGFloat y = ??
    // CGFloat width = ??
    // CGFloat height = ??
    MKMapRect mapRectFromBounds = MKMapRectMake(x,y,width,height);
    return mapRectFromBounds;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bounds can span the 180th meridian, you have to account for that in the conversion:

```
- (MKMapRect) mapRectThatFitsBoundsSW:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)sw 
                                   NE:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)ne 
{
    MKMapPoint pSW = MKMapPointForCoordinate(sw);
    MKMapPoint pNE = MKMapPointForCoordinate(ne);

    double antimeridianOveflow = 
      (ne.longitude > sw.longitude) ? 0 : MKMapSizeWorld.width;    

    return MKMapRectMake(pSW.x, pNE.y, 
                        (pNE.x - pSW.x) + antimeridianOveflow, 
                        (pSW.y - pNE.y));
}
```

But beware those `MKMapRect`s that span the [anitmeridian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimeridian), because they come from the land where the dragons live. If you want to learn about some of the dangers that lie there, have a look at
[MKMapRect and displaying map overlays that span 180th meridian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022490/). You have been warned!

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways to do this.

You could create an `MKCoordinateRegion` by figuring out the `center` point and then the `span` is the absolute difference in degrees between the corners.

Or you could create an `MKMapRect` by using the MapKit function `MKMapPointForCoordinate`.  To get the `origin`, figure out the northwest coordinate and convert it to an `MKMapPoint`.  To get the `width` and `height`, get the absolute difference in **mappoints** between the corners (convert the corners from coordinates to `MKMapPoint`s using the function first).

Another quick way is a slight trick using the `MKMapRectUnion` function.  Create a zero-size `MKMapRect` from each coordinate and then merge the two rects into one big rect using the function:

```
MKMapPoint swPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(SWCoordinate);
MKMapRect swRect = MKMapRectMake(swPoint.x, swPoint.y, 0, 0);

MKMapPoint nePoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(NECoordinate);
MKMapRect neRect = MKMapRectMake(nePoint.x, nePoint.y, 0, 0);

MKMapRect rect = MKMapRectUnion(swRect, neRect);
```

Remember that the map view will still make its own adjustments to the rect you request based on the proportions of the map view and the required zoom.  (If you want to know what that adjusted rect will be, call the map view's `mapRectThatFits:` method.)

Comment: This is a really ingenious trick. Deserves more upvotes for being the least math-y.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works. I ended up going with this:

```
- (MKMapRect) mapRectThatFitsBoundsSW:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)sw 
                                   NE:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)ne {
    MKMapPoint nePoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(ne);
    MKMapPoint swPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(sw);
    CGFloat width = ABS(nePoint.x - swPoint.x);
    CGFloat height = ABS(nePoint.y - swPoint.y);
    MKMapRect newMapRect = MKMapRectMake(
        MIN(swPoint.x, nePoint.x), 
        MIN(swPoint.y, nePoint.y), 
        width, 
        height
    );

    // if (!MKMapRectSpans180thMeridian(newMapRect)) {
        return newMapRect;
    // } else {
        // ????
    // }
}
```

Comment: If you know for sure the NE and SW points are correct (and not swapped to be NW and SE or whatever) then you don't need the ABS. If you're not sure they they will be the correct corners, then you'll need to get the minimum of the two possible x coords as your first parameter to MKMapRectMake. Same for y. Of course, this all relies on you not having any boxes that cross the anti-meridian.

Comment: I can see why it would be nice not to worry about which coordinate is NE or SW, just in case they accidentally get swapped, so I've added the MIN to MKMapRect x and y. How could we handle the anti-meridian issue?

Comment: Since MKMapView doesn't go over the dateline you're not able to draw a box that crosses it either. To determine if the coords you're given really do cross the line you either need to be sure which is NE and which is SW for the box then check if NE is actually further 'west' than SW (in terms of between -180 and +180) if so then the box crosses the line. If you don't know which coordinate belongs in the top-right/bottom-left, then get the absolute difference in their longitude values. >180 means it'd be shorter to go around the other side of the globe.

Comment: @jmcopeland See my answer for solution to "How could we handle the anti-meridian issue".